# IBM Watson using Alchemy API

Tags: ibm-watson, sslhandshakeexception

I am using iOS SDK for IBM Watson Alchemy API. I got my credentials for Alchemy API and used the code in the documentation to call the API (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk). However, I cannot find documentation how to solve the following error:

```
2016-06-14 08:59:14.475 WatsonSpeak[19001:624921] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2016-06-14 08:59:14.475 WatsonSpeak[19001:624921] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection
```

Other APIs like Speech to Text, Concept etc are working following the documentation. However, I am unable to access this API.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this problem.

In the info.plist, in the App Transport Security Settings, 
Add- Allow Arbitrary load and 
Remove- Exceptions.

This will allow authorization.